# How to set up ROS2 Fast DDS discovery server between different networks?

Tags: ros2, network, dds, rmw, fastdds

I'm trying to get ROS2 nodes from two different networks to talk to each other (ROS2 humble, default rmw_fastrtps_cpp, all running on Ubuntu), but no luck. The network topology looks like this:
[host_a 10.8.0.10]  <-> [10.8.0.1 router  192.168.0.1] <-> [192.168.0.4 host_b]

Setting up the discovery server [following the tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Advanced/Discovery-Server/Discovery-Server.html) works *within host_b* (i.e. running both the talker and listener there).
What does *not* work is running the talker on host_b, and the listener on host_a.

On host_b:

```
fastdds discovery -i 0 &
export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER=192.168.0.4:11811
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker --ros-args --remap __node:=talker_discovery_server
```

and on host_a:

```
export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER=192.168.0.4:11811
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener --ros-args --remap __node:=simple_listener_2
```

But no ROS messages arrive. Running the listener on host_b works. I also tried using a super client configuration file, makes no difference.

The ROS_DOMAIN_ID is set to 0 everywhere.

As far as networking is concerned, things seem to check out as well. Running tcpdump (on the client side) shows a pattern of RTPS udp traffic:

```
1   0.000000    10.8.0.10   192.168.0.4 RTPS    420 INFO_TS, DATA(p)
2   0.114741    192.168.0.4 10.8.0.10   RTPS    96  INFO_DST, HEARTBEAT
3   0.114773    192.168.0.4 10.8.0.10   RTPS    96  INFO_DST, HEARTBEAT
4   0.114795    192.168.0.4 10.8.0.10   RTPS    96  INFO_DST, HEARTBEAT
5   0.114818    192.168.0.4 10.8.0.10   RTPS    96  INFO_DST, HEARTBEAT
6   0.554931    10.8.0.10   192.168.0.4 RTPS    428 INFO_TS, DATA(p)
7   1.114675    192.168.0.4 10.8.0.10   RTPS    96  INFO_DST, HEARTBEAT
8   1.114707    192.168.0.4 10.8.0.10   RTPS    96  INFO_DST, HEARTBEAT
9   1.114728    192.168.0.4 10.8.0.10   RTPS    96  INFO_DST, HEARTBEAT
10  1.114748    192.168.0.4 10.8.0.10   RTPS    96  INFO_DST, HEARTBEAT
11  1.851188    192.168.0.4 10.8.0.10   RTPS    596 INFO_TS, DATA(p)
```

What else could be the problem?

Are there any other tools to monitor what's going on?